# ios add array to array in front

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays

I have an existing array to which i want to add an other array in the front of the existing array.

Add to the end is no problem with

```
[existingArray addObjectsFromArray:newArray];
```

But how to add it to the front?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this without a temporary array, and without assuming that `newArray` is an `NSMutableArray`, and without making an `NSIndexSet`:

```
[existingArray replaceObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,0)
                withObjectsFromArray:newArray];
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution.

Answer (score 16):

Same method, but invert the order and re-assign:

```
[newArray addObjectsFromArray:existingArray];
existingArray = newArray;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 [newArray addObjectsFromArray:existingArray];
 existingArray = newArray;
```

Hope,this will help you..enjoy...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a 3rd array and add the elements in the order you want, then asing it back to the first one:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:newArray];
[tempArray addObjectsFromArray:existingArray];
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness' sake here's a very different way:

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange: (NSRange) {0, [newArray count]}];
[existingArray insertObjects: newArray atIndexes: indexes];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add objects to index below code:

```
[existingArray insertObjects:newArray atIndexes:0];
```

Thanks..!

Comment: U will get error [NSMutableArray insertObjects:atIndexes:]: index set cannot be nil

Answer (score 0):

Think the two first answers are more elegant, but here's another way:

Use:

```
[existingArray insertObjects:newArray atIndexes:indexSet];
```

where the `indexSet` runs from `0` to `newArray.count-1` .

Answer (score -2):

To insert jjust before the existing array u must use index 0

```
[newArray insertObject: existingArray atIndex:0]
```

Comment: that whole insert the whole array at index 0